# How should I design a monoid type

Tags: c++, templates

There should be two operations: mempty which is a neutral element and mappend which is an associative binary operation.
I can't decide what would be a proper way to design monoid. I could use template specialization

```
template<typename T>
T mappend(const T &left_operand, const T &right_operand);

template<typename T>
T mempty();

struct Min {
    int value;
};

template<>
Min mappend<Min>(const Min &left_operand, const Min &right_operand) {
    return {std::min(left_operand.value, right_operand.value)};
}

template<>
Min mempty<Min>() {
    return {std::numeric_limits<int>::max()};
}

int main() {
    Min m1{1};
    Min m2{3};
    std::cout << mappend(mempty<Min>(), mappend(m1, m2)).value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, this way I can't make sure that both mappend and mempty are specialized for the class.

Another way would be to create a template class

```
template<typename ValueT, ValueT Identity, typename AppendT, AppendT Append>
class Monoid {
    static constexpr ValueT EMPTY = Identity;
    static constexpr AppendT APPEND = Append;

    ValueT value = Identity;
public:

    using monoid = Monoid<ValueT, Identity, AppendT, Append>;

    constexpr Monoid() noexcept = default;

    constexpr explicit Monoid(const ValueT &value) noexcept : value(value) {};

    constexpr ValueT getValue() const noexcept {
        return value;
    }

    template<typename V, V I, typename AT, AT A>
    friend constexpr monoid
    mappend(const monoid &left_operand, const monoid &right_operand) {
        return {APPEND(left_operand.value, right_operand.value)};
    }

    template<typename V, V I, typename AT, AT A>
    friend constexpr monoid
    mempty() {
        return EMPTY;
    }
};
int main() {
    auto add = [](const int &x1, const int &x2) { return x1 + x2; };
    using Sum = Monoid<int, 0, decltype(add), add>;
    Sum m1(2);
    Sum m2(3);
    std::cout << Sum::mappend(Sum::mappend(m1, m2), Sum::mempty()).getValue() << std::endl;
}
```

Which doesn't compile because I can't pass lambda as template parameter.

I would like to know if there is a better design or how I should fix what I have

Comment: *this way I can't make sure that both mappend and mempty are specialized for the class.* - sounds like a job for a Concept. Your example is simple enough that the errors popping up would be close enough to the impl; the real problems start when you pass your classes as parameters.

Comment: I wouldn't call them mappend and mempty - this reads bad; in mind, you get first to map -> mapped -> error(!) -> m + append, mem -> memory -> erorr(!) -> m + empty... If at all, write m_... or mXyz, better just skip the prefix entirely...

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz -- It looks interesting but would take time to wrap my head around. They are also not available for c++17, right? Thanks anyway

Comment: @Aconcagua -- You are right, probably. I just borrowed Haskell names for now

Comment: Could you restrict yourself to default-constructable `AppendT`s? In this example you can replace the lambda with `std::plus<>`

Comment: `template <typename Arithmetic> using Sum = Monoid<Arithmetic, 0, std::plus<Arithmetic>>; template <typename Arithmetic> using Product = Monoid<Arithmetic, 1, std::multiplies<Arithmetic>>; ` are legal definitions

Comment: @Caleth -- Default-constructible append works fine. It might be not very elegant for custom operations but it works. I might accept your solution if you write an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can restrict the type of `Append` to the concept `DefaultConstructible`, then don't have to have an instance of one to declare a `Monoid`. Types like `std::plus<>` fit well as arguments to a `Monoid`

```
template <typename Arithmetic> 
using Sum = Monoid<Arithmetic, 0, std::plus<Arithmetic>>; 
template <typename Arithmetic> 
using Product = Monoid<Arithmetic, 1, std::multiplies<Arithmetic>>;
```